# How can I define an absolute path saved in one exe file?

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I'm writing a software in python for windows which should be connected to a database. Using py2exe i want to make an executable file so that I don't have to install python in the machines the software is running. The problem is that I want the user to define where the database is located the very first time the software starts, but I don't know how to store this information so that the user doesn't have to tell everytime where is the database. I have no idea how to deal with it. (the code cannot be changed because it's just a .exe file). How would you do that?

Comment: wrap with a .bat file which asks for the location then sets it in an environment variable using setx. Ask only the location if the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: that said, if you're writing the software, why can't you change it?

Comment: Create an ini or similar config file in the users home directory

Comment: @Marged, not the home directory. It's impolite to pollute a user's home directory with config files, especially since there's no convention to hide them in Windows. You can't set the hidden attribute since it makes the file unable to be overwritten via `open`. A subdirectory can be hidden, but there's already a hidden "AppData" directory that's meant for this use case. It has "Local" and "Roaming" subdirectories. "Roaming" is for application data that should roam with the user profile to other machines.

Comment: @eryksun I have several invisible folders created by Linux style applications in my home. But your point is correct: the database is most likely machine specific, so the config should be written to local app data and not roam

Comment: @Marged, directories in Windows can be flagged as a hidden with no problem, but it doesn't work well for individual configuration files. They typically get overwritten when modified, but the underlying [`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew?) call in that case (i.e. `CREATE_ALWAYS` disposition) requires including an existing hidden (or system) attribute in `dwFlagsAndAttributes`. The `open` function of C and Python does not support this. In Unix, OTOH, hiding a file by using a dot name is just a convention.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of some solutions:

- You can assume the DB is in a fixed location - bad idea, might move or change name and then your program stop working
- You can assume the DB is in the same folder as the .exe file and guide the user to run it in the same folder - better but still not perfect
- Ask the user for the DB location and save the path in a configuration file. If the file doesn't exist or path doesn't lead to the file, the user should tell the program where is the DB, otherwise, read it from the config file - I think this is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
default_db_path = os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA'] + '/stuff.db'
setting_path = os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA'] + '/.stuff_db_path.txt'
try:
    open(setting_path)
except:
    with open(setting_path, 'wt') as f:
        f.write(default_db_path)
db_path = open(setting_path).read().strip()
```

This way, the user is able to configure via the text file, and you're able to have a sensible default for the first time.

**Edit:** added a Windows friendly config path, which should work in most private and corporate environments. There are innumerous ways to improve this example, but my suggestion is you start out [simple stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and take it from there.

Comment: This code is dependent upon what the current working directory is because the file path is relative to that. How do you suggest fixing that limitation?

Comment: The working directory is arbitrary and unreliable, and the directory of the executable may not be writable by the current process. The application should define and document its own subdirectory of the user's application data directory. The easiest way to get the application data directory is via the environment variable `os.environ['APPDATA']`. But the most reliable way is via the shell API [`SHGetFolderPathW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) w/ `CSIDL_APPDATA`, which you can easily call with ctypes:

Comment: `import ctypes;` `CSIDL_APPDATA = 26;` `SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;` `buf = (ctypes.c_wchar * 260)();` `ctypes.OleDLL('shell32').SHGetFolderPathW(None, CSIDL_APPDATA, None, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, buf);` `appdata = buf.value`

Comment: In the context of an organization that uses roaming user profiles, if the location of the database is expected to vary depending on the machine, then this should use `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = 28` instead. In this case, if a user signs on to a new system and runs the app, it will prompt them for the database location on the current system. The corresponding environment variable is `os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA']`. This variable is pretty reliable, if nothing has tampered with it, because it isn't possible in recent versions of Windows for a user to relocate this folder.